# elementary symmetric function identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions

I want to evaluate the following sum:

$\sum_{\lambda}e_k(\lambda)$ where the sum is over all partitions $\lambda$ that fit in an $m$ by $n$ grid and where $e_k(\lambda):=e_k(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_m)$ for $\lambda$ possibly padded with zeros if $\lambda$ does not have $m$ parts. Also $k\leq m$.

Comment: What sort of evaluation do you have in mind? Already for $k=1$ the answer is given by the derivative of the gaussian binomial coefficient at 1. I don't think that has a product formula, for example.

Comment: The $k=1$ case I have an explicit expression for, it is the Stirling number of the second kind $S(m+n,n)$. I was hoping for other "nice" combinatorial interpretations.

Comment: I don't seem to understand. Is $e_k$ the $k$th elementary symmetric function? Then the sum for $k=1$ is ${m+n\choose m}$ times the average size of a partition fitting in an $m\times n$ grid. This average size is $\frac{mn}{2}$, giving $\frac{mn}{2}{m+n\choose m}$, not $S(m+n,n)$.

Comment: It appears to me that there is a need to clear up the meaning of $e_k$. So, let us fix it. Let $e_k(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_m)$ denote the (standard) elementary symmetric function, where for example, $e_0(\lambda)=1, e_1(\lambda)=\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_m$ and $e_m(\lambda)=\lambda_1\cdots\lambda_m$. Therefore, $\sum e_1(\lambda)=\frac{mn}2\binom{n+m}m$ is correct as in Stanley's comment. Now, "user162496" is correct only when the comment is written as $\sum e_m(\lambda)=S(n+m,n)$ (provable by induction on $m$).  It is obvious but $\sum e_0(\lambda)=\binom{n+m}m$.

Comment: Thank you to both Richard Stanley and T. Amdeberhan. I was incorrect. I meant to say that $\sum e_m(\lambda)=S(n+m,n)$, as T. Amdeberhan noted. In general, is there a "nice" closed form for $\sum_{\lambda}e_k(\lambda)$ for $k$ between $2$ and $m-1$?

Comment: One more question, is there a name for the polynomial $P(x)=\sum_{\lambda}\prod_i(x-\lambda_i)$, summed over all $\lambda$ fitting in the $m$ by $n$ box? It can be shown that this is the same polynomial as $\sum_{\lambda}(-1)^ie_i(\lambda)x^{m-i}$ where $e_i$ is the $i$th symmetric function in $m$ variables.

Comment: A fun fact is that  $e_{(l-k)}(\lambda)$ equals the coefficient of $t^k$ in $\prod (\lambda + t )$ where $l$ is the length of $\lambda$  ;     
Example: $e_{2}({2,2,1}) = 8$ and the coefficient of $t$ in $(2+t)(2+t)(1+t)$ is $8$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not expect a nice closed formula for arbitrary $k$, in general. However, we could use the following recursive relation to extract some evaluations. This recurrence, we're alluding to, is already immediate from that of the elementary symmetric functions. Denote the given sum in the problem by
$$F_k(m,n)=\sum_{\lambda}e_k(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_m)$$
where $\lambda\subset m\times n$. Then, we have
$$F_k(m,n+1)=\sum_{a=0}^{n+1}aF_{k-1}(m-1,a)+\sum_{a=0}^{n+1}F_k(m-1,a),$$
together with $F_k(k,n)=S(n+k,n)$ as noted above.

For example, we know $F_0(m,n)=\binom{n+m}m$. Therefore, starting with $F_1(1,a)=S(a+1,a)=\binom{a+1}2$ one can build $F_1(m,n)=\frac{nm}2\binom{n+m}m$, successively.

Another example is, based on $F_1(m,n)$, the evaluation
$$F_2(m,n)=\binom{n+m}m\frac{n(3n+1)m(m-1)}{24}.$$